# Control Nav Bar Tints with PSPDF

Tags: ios, objective-c, pspdfkit

Hi I have a PSPDFViewController embedded in a UINavigationController which I then have as the left controller in a splitview controller.

I have set the colour of the navbar to match the right hand controllers nav bar however it seems PSPDFKit is changeing the colour or alpha slightly. Is there any way I can turn this off?

[image]

Here is how I'm creating the controller:

```
PSPDFViewController *pspdfController = [[PSPDFViewController alloc] initWithDocument:document];
UINavigationController *pspdfNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pspdfController];

pspdfNavigationController.barTintColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:252.0/255.0 green:14.0/255.0 blue:47.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];;
pspdfNavigationController.backgroundColor = [[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:252.0/255.0 green:14.0/255.0 blue:47.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
pspdfNavigationController.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
navbar.translucent = NO;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lulz:

```
self.transparentHUD = NO;
```